# Return distinct elements from a sequence of words

Tags: c#, list, distinct

supposing I have a List with some words like this:

```
List<string> words = new List<string>{ "apple", "computer", "user", "AppLe", "USer", "photo", "USER" };
```

and I want to produce a new list like this:

```
List<string> newWords = new List<string>{ "apple", "computer", "user", "photo" };
```

How can I clean the first list from all the multiple words (no matter how they are written)?

many thanks in advance,
Filippo

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
List<string> newWords = words.Distinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToList();
```

This way you don't change any words in the resulting list (e.g. making them lowercase).

You can also use: [`StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.currentcultureignorecase(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.invariantcultureignorecase(v=vs.110).aspx), depending on your culture requirements.

Comment: Hi, I get an error because the first one is "System.Collections.Generic.List<string>" and the other one is "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>"...

Comment: Just add a call to .ToList() at the end of the function.

Comment: @user3283415 Oh. My bad. You need to add a .ToList(). `Distinct` return an `IEnumerable<string>`. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> words = new List<string> { "apple", "computer", "user", "AppLe", "USer", "photo", "USER" };
words = words.Select(x => x.ToLower()).Distinct().ToList();
```